# The limit of Int32 for Identity Column

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, identity-column, type-conversion

This is just a consideration for a site am creating and for other big sites out there.

I am using Identity Column to store the ID of some of my tables and I have classes whose Id are decorated with `Int32` to hold the value of the ID retrieved from database.

My worry is that as the site grows bigger, some tables that grows exponentially e.g `QuestionComments` might exceed the `Int32` limit in future. So I change my class to use `long`.

```
public class Question
{
   public long QuestionID { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

//Converting database value to .Net type

```
 Question q = new Question();
 q.QuestionID = Convert.ToInt32(myDataRow["QuestionID"]);
```

How true is my assumption? Would using a UniqueIdentifier be better? Are there other way to address this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you imagine billions of records being stored for any one entity? If so you could switch to `BigInt` which is otherwise known as `Int64`. Of course once you start seeing many millions of records you need to start thinking about data partitioning and archiving to avoid serious performance issues. If you have a infrastructure team you may want to let them know that you expect heavy usage and will need a serious maintenance plan. If you are the infrastructure team then you better hit the books!

Comment: Thanks. I posted the same question on Programmer.SE and received more explanation. Int32 is actually big, 2 Billion (2,147,483,647) unique IDs. That's enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you really think it's reasonable that you'll have over 2 billion comments, then use `BIGINT` in SQL Server (`Int64` in .Net). This requires 8 bytes of storage instead of 4 bytes for `INT`, however you can offset this for the first 2+billion values if you use data compression.

Comment: am honoured to have your answer. Thanks